# Given $\Omega\in \Bbb{R}^n$ and $u\in C^2$ in neighborhood of $\bar{\Omega}$, show that $u=0$ in $\Omega$

Tags: calculus

I trying to solve the following question, but to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

> Let $\Omega\in \Bbb{R}^n$ be smooth domain. Let $u\in C^2$ in the neighborhood of $\bar{\Omega}$, such that $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and $\triangle u=u$ in $\Omega$.
>
> show that $u=0$ in $\Omega$.

I tried to assume that $u$ is not constant (in particular not zero) and then use the fact it has an extreme point, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!